# How to give two name at a time to get a query?

Tags: soql

```
   list<Contact> conlist = [select id, Email, Communication_Agreement__c 
                            from Contact 
                            where name='ajay'];
```

Comment: It's not really clear ! What do you mean by two names ?

Comment: where name='ajay','vijay' like that.how to see  another record id,email,Communication_Agreement__c.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use the `AND` or `OR` in your query:

```
   list<Contact> conlist = [select id, Email, Communication_Agreement__c 
                            from Contact 
                            where name = 'ajay'
                            OR name = 'blaah'];
```

Additionaly you can create a list with multiple values and use `IN`:

```
List<String> mylist = new List<String>();
l.add('param1');
l.add('param2');

list<Contact> conlist = [select id, Email, Communication_Agreement__c 
                         from Contact 
                         where name IN :mylist];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
Set<String> nameval=new Set<String>();
nameval.add('Test');
nameval.add('Test_1');
List<Contact> conlist = [Select Id,Email,Communication_Agreement__c from Contact where name in: nameval];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
list<Contact> conlist = [select id, Name, Email,Communication_Agreement__c 
                            from Contact 
                            where Name='ajay'
                            or Name='vijay'];
```